# Xamarin.Android: Automatically refresh the display of an ImageView without calling the whole activity again

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, refresh

In my Xamarin.Android-App, when opening a special page (activity), there is a table displayed on create.
A ListAdapter defines the certain fields within that table.
I have a function which gets me an external int. The int is amongst other data displayed in that table. 
But this function is only called once (on create).
How can I call this function multible time during runtime within a certain time interval? I want that if this received int changes, the display of the int in the table changes as well without calling the whole activity again.

Can anyone maybe help me and give me a hint how to do this? That would really be very kind!

Please let me share some code, so it's maybe easier for you to understand me:

Resource.Layout.Activity:

```
<LinearLayout>
    [...]
    <ListView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ListView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity);
    [...]    
    var lv = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView);
    lv.Adapter = new ListAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.List, list.CurrentList, Intent.GetStringExtra("ServerIP"));
}
```

Resource.Layout.List:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
android:orientation="horizontal"     
android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

[...]

<ImageView         
    android:id="@+id/ImageView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

class ListAdapter : ArrayAdapter

```
public ListAdapter(Context Context, int ListId, List<Geraet> list, string serverip) : base(Context, ListId, Geraete)
{ 
    this.List = list; 
}
```

[...]

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
        v = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.List, parent, false);
    }
    if (Get_Status(List[position]) == 1)
    {
        v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImageView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.green);
    }
    if (Get_Status(List[position]) != 1)
    {
        v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImageView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.red);
    }
}
```

[...]

```
private int Get_Status(Geraet geraet)
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(Constants.StatusPath, Serverip, Constants.WebservicePort, geraet.Ip));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, @"[^0-9]", "");

            if (result == string.Empty)
            {
                return -2;
            }
            else
            {
                return Int32.Parse(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for answers in advance and best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `System.Threading`:

```
var thread = new Thread(() => MethodToRun(garaet));
thread.Start();
```

Run the above code in `OnCreate()`. In `MethodToRun()` you can do whatever you want. For example:

```
void MethodToRun(Garaet garaet) {
    while(true) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Activity.RunOnUiThread((garaet) => { [...] });
    }
}
```

In this case, `[...]` will run every one second on the UI thread. Replace that with the code that handles image updating.

Comment: Sorry that I write you again. When trying to insert code that handles image updating, he underlines Activity.RunOnUiThread saying "an object reference is needed". Please see:

    private void MethodToRun(){
        while (true){
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {
            int status = Get_Status(geraet);
            if (status == 1){v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImageView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.green);}
            if (status != 1){v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.ImageView).SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.red);}});}

Comment: @Sam try this: 
`Thread thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(garaet))`

and change `MethodToRun()` to `MethodToRun(Garaet garaet)`

Comment: Hmm, now he underlines geraet in ParameterizedThreadStart(geraet) saying "method name expected", and when I change geraet to MethodToRun(geraet) it has no effect (same error) :(

Comment: Thank you really for your help and sorry that I have to write you so much. When changing this to the code you updated, now he underlines `new ParameterizedThreadStart(MethodToRun)` saying "_no override for (/of?^^) "MethodToRun" matches (/correspond to?^^) to the delegates "ParameterizedThreadStart"_" Again sorry for my newbie questions and my bad english.

Comment: Now he underlines Activity.RunOnUiThread again saying "an object reference is needed". :D

Comment: Oh man I am really sorry for writing again xD now everything after `(geraet) => {[...]};` is underlined, the error message reads: _lambda expression could not be converted to type "IRunnable", because it is no delegate. A local variable or a parameter called "geraet" could not be declared within this place, because it's name is used in an embedded local area for defining a local variable or parameter_

Comment: I found something out myself haha :D if I change `Activity.RunOnUiThread` to `var a = new Activity(); a.RunOnUiThread([...]);` the reference error is gone. But may I do this? Is this correct?^^

Comment: Hm no I may not do this. Now I get an exception during runtime in the line `var a = new Activity();` saying _Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()_